# If $E[|X|^k]$ exists, does $E[|X|^m]$ exist for $0 \leq m \leq k$?

Tags: expected-value

The question is:

> If $E[|X|^k]$ exists, does $E[|X|^m]$ exist for $0 \leq m \leq k$? If so, can you prove it?

Here $X$ is just a generic random variable.

I don't know how to solve this problem. I thought about approaching it by first defining
$g(x, i) = |x|^i$ for some $i \in \mathbb{R}^+$.

$$
E[g(x,i)] = \int_{x_{\min}}^{x_{\max}} g(x,i) f_X(x) \\
E[g(x,k)] = \int_{x_{\min}}^{x_{\max}} g(x,k) f_X(x) = c
$$

where $c$ is some constant. I don't know if this is the right direction or not? Could someone advise?

Comment: Apply Holder's inequality.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Ah I'm not familiar with that inequality, but I'll look into it. Is there also a more first principles approach to solving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.
$$
\begin{align*}
E[|X|^m] &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |x|^m f_X(x) dx \\
  &=  \int_{ |x| \leq 1  } |x|^m f_X(x) dx + \int_{ |x| > 1  } |x|^m f_X(x) dx \\
&\leq 1 + \int_{ |x| > 1  } |x|^k f_X(x) dx \leq 1 + E[|X|^k] < \infty
\end{align*}
 $$

Comment: $X$ needs not admit a probability density function.

Comment: @DannyPak-KeungChan If you swap out the integrals for sums, don't we get an analogous result for pmfs?

Comment: Is correct, we do (just use pmf instead of pdf in that case).

Comment: Does your result change if it was a piecewise pdf instead of a connected one?

Comment: No, I've made no assumptions on the pdf apart from the two standard ones: always non-negative, and integral over R is 1.

Comment: Wait, why is $\int_{|x| > 1} |x|^k f_X(x) dx \leq E[|X|^k] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |x|^k f_X(x) dx$?

Comment: LHS $\leq \int_{\mathbb{R}} |x|^k f_X(x) dx = $ RHS.

Comment: Hmm, but what if we have $X \sim U(-0.5, 2)$? Then $E[|X|^k] < \int_{|x| > 1} |x|^k f_X(x)dx$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122560/discussion-between-kaind-and-user5965026).